# Why is 'Rabbenu Tam' called Rabbenu Tam?

Tags: history, names, rishonim, rabbeinu-tam

Rabbenu Tam's name was יעקב בן מאיר. Why then is he known as Rabbenu Tam?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*Ya'akov Avinu* was known as an [*ish **tam***](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A9_%D7%AA%D7%9D_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%91_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D). Since they shared the first name Ya'akov (and possibly some [personal character traits](https://web.archive.org/web/20140831231516/http://www.ypt.co.il/show.asp?id=19203)), one's appelation was applied to the other.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: The ריב"ש linked makes it clear that at least his use of "תם" was an allusion to _Ya'akov Avinu_, albeit a good 150 years after ר"ת lived.

Comment: Also Rabbeinu Poras whose name was Yosef, same story I've always assumed

Answer (score 9):

I've heared that Rabbenu Tam made a *gzeira* that cancels the curse of "ו **תם** לריק כוחכם", hence he is called Tam. [See Tosfos to Kesuvos 47b, and Sefer Hayashar 788]

[Here](http://www.mytzadik.com/tadik.asp?kever_id=389&safaid=6) is a source that states this.

Comment: Very strange that he is nicknamed after the curse and not the refuah.

Comment: He *canceled* the curse, it's may be called type of refuah.

Comment: So it's a double play on words that the gezeirah of "Tam" was Tam?

Comment: It's not a play on words, you don't need the lat Tam. Just: "He canceled gzeira of Tam".

Comment: So, if he would have stopped the curse of pestilence they would call him Rabbeinu Dever??

Comment: what's that curse?

Comment: Can you please [edit] this post to explain which *gzeira* you refer to? Also, your link is dead. (It looks like you may be able to use http://www.daat.ac.il/encyclopedia/value.asp?id1=1684; there's a הערה on the bottom of the page that quotes a similar idea, citing הגהות מהרי"ד על התו"כ (בחוקותי א' א"ג

Comment: Another source for this is brought in the סדר דורות הקצר on p.143

Answer (score 4):

In addition to WAF's answer, which is definitely correct, we need to add one thing. There were many rabbis named יעקב who did not get called תם (R. Yaakov of Orleans, R. Yaakov ben Yakar and others). Why did specifically this יעקב get to be רבינו תם?

To quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi#Descendants),

> Rashi's oldest daughter, Yocheved, married Meir ben Samuel; their four sons were Shmuel (Rashbam) (born 1080), Yitzchak (Rivam) (born 1090), Jacob (Rabbeinu Tam) (born 1100), and Shlomo the Grammarian, all of whom were among the most prolific of the Baalei Tosafot, leading rabbinic authorities who wrote critical and explanatory glosses on the Talmud which appear opposite Rashi's commentary on every page of the Talmud.

The second and third sons are יצחק and יעקב, which when given their acronym, would have two people named ריב׳׳ם. To distinguish between R. Yitzchak ben Meir and R. Yaakov ben Meir, we call Yaakov "תם", for the reason that WAF explained: יעקב איש תם, to avoid confusion between the two brothers.

Comment: Interesting idea! Did you come up with this or is it mentioned elsewhere (maybe even in Rishonim)?

Comment: Never saw it in print. I always thought it was kind of obvious though.